# Rails random choose from table column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building rails quiz app. I have model question with columns category, question_input and answer.
So I need to randomly choose 7 category names from table question - column categories and display them in view.
And after that i will do the same with the question_input (randomly choose 10 question) from each chosen category.
So I stuck here and I need some help.

Below is my Model.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base   
CATEGORIES = %w(history geography art literature comics movie music culture religion mithology sport technology science politics)   
validates :category, inclusion: { in: CATEGORIES }, presence: true   
validates :question_input, presence: true   
validates :answer, presence: true 
end
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose categories and questions like this:

```
categories = CATEGORY.sample(7)
questions = Question.where(category: categories)
categories.map do |category| 
  questions.select { |q| q.category == category }.sample(10)
end
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong here. Am I choosing categories in model and questions in controller?  Or i completely messed up this?

Comment: yes, you can. But better solution is put all this logic in model, because this code works with database.

Comment: Thanks. And I have a last question. So when I put all logic in model how can I call categories and these questions in view?

Comment: You can split this logic on two methods: `Question.rand_categories` and `Question.rand_questions_by_categories(categories)`.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.

Comment: Also, this produces arrays with possibly duplicated questions.

Comment: now it's much better, except that CATEGORIES is not a model, just a set of strings. "choose 7 category names from table question - column categories" as the OP says.

Comment: `questions.select { |q| q.category = category }.sample(10)` it may be `questions.select { |q| q.category == category }.sample(10)` right? Anyway you are completely changing your answer from the initial one, I think it's not really the right way to deal with errors in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
CATEGORIES.sample 7
```

See docs on how to use: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample

Answer (score 0):

Once you select (as others point out) the category from your ruby array (using http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) then you should let the database return a random sample of records for you:

```
# MySQL
Question.where(category: chosen_category).order("RAND()").limit(10)

# Postgres
Question.where(category: chosen_category).order("random()").limit(10)
```

If you don't have many questions, it might be better to do the question sampling in ruby too. Check your numbers.

```
grouped_questions = Questions.all().group_by(&:category).each do |cat, qns|
  [cat, qns.sample(10)]
end.to_h
# Now grouped_questions is a hash with:
# {
#    category: [array of 10 random questions in that category],
#    ...
# }
```

Comment: 1 query only, as said in the text between the two proposals. Either you have many questions, in which case loading them all and then sampling from ruby will kill your machine, so it's better to let the databas do the sampling. Or you don't have many questions, in which case it's better to load all the questions and sample in ruby. The point at which this changes depends on too many factors to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Anyway, it will better to load only questions with chosen categories instead of all.